# I want to get the values appeared in a link using requests.get but no values exist in html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to get the values within a web page using the following python code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://www2.usgs.gov/water/lowermississippigulf/lmgweb/meras/cell_log.html?longitude=-90&latitude=35&x_coordinate=542742.2705864373&y_coordinate=1343939.7318854574'
page = requests.get(url)
```

However, the `page.content` shows no numeric value. It seems that the page provides graphical outputs not numeric values of a tabular output. Can you help me to tackle this issue and get the table inside the web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the request to the wrong url try the following code:

```
import requests


url = "https://www2.usgs.gov:443/water/lowermississippigulf/cgi/meras/framework/framework_well_log.pl?longitude=-90&latitude=35&x_coordinate=542742.2705864373&y_coordinate=1343939.7318854574&rasters=tiffs/alvm_surf.tif%20tiffs/vkbg_surf.tif%20tiffs/ucaq_surf.tif%20tiffs/mccu_surf.tif%20tiffs/mcaq_surf.tif%20tiffs/lccu_surf.tif%20tiffs/lcaq_surf.tif%20tiffs/mwaq_surf.tif%20tiffs/lwaq_surf.tif%20tiffs/mdwy_surf.tif&color=framework_color_map.txt"
page = requests.get(url).json()
```

A JSON string is returned which is why I'm using `.json()` at the end (you can always change `.json()` to `.content`)